# How to increment rows in grid view automatically

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am creating a windows form that will take the details of employees and those will be automatically appended to grid view by using data table. I am able to append the details in grid view for only one row. Each time that is getting overwritten.

What to do if I wanted to add each time to new row?

Comment: Post the code you are currently using please.

Comment: Please post your code, how you are adding rows in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a datatable, right? So, you can add rows into the datatable and then bind it to gridview.

Adding rows to a datatable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx

Binding a datatable to gridview:

```
this.dataGridView2.DataSource = myTable;
```